# How to fix single-row subquery returns more than one row in below query?

Tags: sql, oracle

When i execute the this query, I get the following error message :

> "Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
UPDATE event_registrations xta
SET (event_start_date,
     event_end_date,
     planned_hours,
     user_status,
     last_updated_date,
     last_updated_by,
     last_update_sec) =
     (SELECT xcat.event_start_date,
          CASE
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_closed_s THEN xta.event_end_date
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_open_s THEN xcat.event_end_date
          END,
          xcat.planned_hours,
          CASE
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_closed_s THEN g_status_done
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_open_s THEN g_status_inprogress
          END,
          SYSDATE,
          p_login_user,
          to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, g_time_format))

   FROM     event_registrations_temp xcat
   LEFT     OUTER JOIN EVENTS xt ON xt.ext_system_id = xcat.alm_id
   WHERE    xcat.action = g_action_modification
   AND      xcat.error_flag = g_err_flag_not_processed
   AND      xcat.event_registration_id = xta.ext_event_registration_id)
   WHERE    xta.ext_event_registration_id IN
            (SELECT event_registration_id
             FROM   event_registrations_temp
             WHERE  action = g_action_modification
             AND    error_flag = g_err_flag_not_processed);
```

**I tried to fix it by using IN condition but it did't work**. Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Well, this kind of error may mean that the query logic is poorly constructed - the designer thought that the subquery would always return one record X, and here the real world's surprise - it returns X and Y and maybe Z. You may have to rewrite the query from scratch. Describe what the query should do - what are the requirements ?

Comment: the only way is you can check and rewrite query again which return you a desired single record. Or you can get single record by LIMIT also. But it purely based on your use case and logic.

Comment: This is all about a part of a procedure which is able to update a excising events that belongs to a particular campaign.

Comment: there is no way to fix that automatically. you must change the query and also need to verify the data again so you can make query more reliable and to avoid future errors like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subquery that is to return the values for the update returns more than one record. So either

- `event_registrations_temp` can contain more than one record per `action` + `error_flag` + `event_registration_id`

or

- there are multiple `events` per `ext_system_id`.

**Checking `event_registrations_temp`:**

```
select action, error_flag, event_registration_id
from event_registrations_temp
group by action, error_flag, event_registration_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

**Checking `events`:**

```
select ext_system_id
from events
group by ext_system_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Once you know which of the two issues it is, make up your mind how to decide for the one record you want for the update and add this criteria to your subquery. This can be additional criteria in your `WHERE` clause or some aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as 'correlated update' and IN is not the solution.
But still before using it in update you need to check the select statement first.

```
UPDATE event_registrations xta
SET (event_start_date,
     event_end_date,
     planned_hours,
     user_status,
     last_updated_date,
     last_updated_by,
     last_update_sec) =
     (SELECT xcat.event_start_date,
          CASE
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_closed_s THEN xta.event_end_date
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_open_s THEN xcat.event_end_date
          END,
          xcat.planned_hours,
          CASE
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_closed_s THEN g_status_done
              WHEN xt.event_status = g_open_s THEN g_status_inprogress
          END,
          SYSDATE,
          p_login_user,
          to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, g_time_format))

   FROM     event_registrations_temp xcat
   LEFT     OUTER JOIN EVENTS xt ON xt.ext_system_id = xcat.alm_id
   WHERE    xcat.action = g_action_modification
   AND      xcat.error_flag = g_err_flag_not_processed
   AND      xcat.event_registration_id = xta.ext_event_registration_id)
   WHERE    xta.ext_event_registration_id =xcat.event_registration_id)
  where  exists (SELECT 1
      FROM event_registrations_temp xcat
     WHERE xcat.event_registration_id = xta.ext_event_registration_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem..Check whether event_registrations_temp can contain more than one record per action or error_flag or event_registration_id

```
select action, error_flag, event_registration_id
from event_registrations_temp
group by action, error_flag, event_registration_id
having count(*) > 1;
```